# Java.lang.nullpointerexception: attempt to invoke virtual method void androidx.recyclerview.widget.recyclerview.setlayoutmanager

Tags: kotlin, recyclerview, nullpointerexception, android-recyclerview

Buenas tengo un problema en donde intento hacer un `androidx.recyclerview.widget.recyclerview.setlayoutmanager` que muestre las fotos que publicas en tu perfil pero me arroja el siguiente error`java.lang.nullpointerexception: attempt to invoke virtual method void androidx.recyclerview.widget.recyclerview.setlayoutmanager(androidx.recyclerview.widget.recyclerview$layoutmanager) on a null object reference`

Entiendo que el dicho error es porque el recyclerview no esta recibiendo ningun dato pero no entiendo el porque, aqui esta mi codigo

**ProfileFragment**

```js
class ProfileFragment : Fragment() {
    private var postList: MutableList<Post>? = null
    private var postAdapter: PostAdapter? = null
    private var usersList: MutableList<Post>? = null

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container,   false)

        var recyclerView: RecyclerView? = null
        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_home)
        val linearLayoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
        linearLayoutManager.reverseLayout = true
        linearLayoutManager.stackFromEnd = true
        recyclerView.layoutManager = linearLayoutManager

        postList = ArrayList()
        postAdapter = context?.let { PostAdapter(it, postList as ArrayList<Post>) }
        recyclerView.adapter = postAdapter

        perfilPost()

    private fun perfilPost() {
        usersList = ArrayList()

        var postRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("Posts")
        var usersRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("Users")
            .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!.uid)

        usersRef.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
                if (p0.exists()) {
                    (usersList as ArrayList<String>).clear()

                    for (snapshot in p0.children) {
                        snapshot.key?.let { (usersList as ArrayList<String>).add(it) }
                    }
                }
            }

            override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {

            }
        })

        postRef.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {

            override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
                postList?.clear()

                for (snapshot in p0.children){
                    val post = snapshot.getValue(Post::class.java)

                    for (id in (usersList as ArrayList<String>)){
                        if (post!!.getPublisher() == id){
                            postList!!.add(post)
                        }

                        postAdapter!!.notifyDataSetChanged()
                    }
                }
            }

            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {

            }
        })
    }
}
```

**Fragmen profile**

```css
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Fragments.ProfileFragment">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/profile_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        </RelativeLayout>

    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

    <ScrollView>

    </ScrollView>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/image_recycler"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_below="@+id/scroll_view">

    </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Nose exactamente cual es error, ya he probado diferentes maneras pero siempre me arroja el mismo resultado, nose si existe una manera mas simple de que cualquier persona vea los post en el perfil, por favor agradeceria muchisimo su ayuda.

Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que tratas de obtener la referencia del `RecyclerView` con id `recycler_view_home` ,

```
 recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_home)
```

pero este `RecyclerView` no se encuentra en el layout `fragment_profile.xml` que carga tu Fragment. No puedes hacer referencia a una vista que se encuentra en otro layout, debe ser el que cargas en tu Fragment.

Comment: Muchas gracias, no me habia dado cuenta